# How to create a log and export to S3 bucket by executing a Python Lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

From my Lambda Python code, I'm trying to create a log to my S3 bucket (s3://my_bucket/logs/) and throwing an error. It is working fine when I execute outside & generating logs. 
Error is below:

```
**[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/s3:/my_bucket/logs/error.log': 
FileNotFoundError.**
```

When this line of code is encountered in my local environment, it is creating the log properly:

```
`LOGFILE_PATH = "D:\logs\error.log"`
```

And when i tried using Lambda after updating it to :

```
LOGFILE_PATH = "s3://my_bucket/logs/" . It is throwing the error when executed using Lambda function.

LOGFILE_PATH = "D:\logs\error.log"  -- working code in local exec.
```

It should generate the log in my S3 bucket. But it's not creating it. I doubt whether we can write logs to S3 from Lambda execution?

Thanks.

Comment: I have resolved this issue my side and its working fine now. Thanks...

Comment: LOGFILE_PATH = "/tmp/error.log" . ---> This way i'm able to create logs in /tmp directory when i execute my Lambda function. Later i'm copying my log file (error.log) from /tmp 
 to my S3 bucket.  So, directly Lambda is not allowing to create logs to S3.

Comment: s3 = boto3.resource('s3')  s3.Bucket('MyBucket').upload_file('/tmp/error.log', 'error.log').  Finally /tmp/error.log file copying to S3 bucket using these lines of code. My issue completely resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The notation you've used `s3://my_bucket/logs/` is not a real address, it's a kind of shorthand, mostly only used when using the AWS CLI `s3` service, that won't work in the same way as a URL or file system path; If you want to write to a bucket (instead of a local file) then from a python lambda you should probably be using [`boto3` and its `s3` client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) to store the file - it also depends on what exactly you're doing in your code with the `LOGFILE_PATH` variable.